# fix multiple broken junctions

Tags: windows-7, ntfs-junction

i have a bunch of broken junction because of drive letter changes.
is there a possibility to mass-fix the drive letter?
Since all the junctions are relative to a common directory root, they also could been completely drive letter independent. Is there some elegant way to handle this?